# PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I know a little regular expression. My question is:
I have a string which can be one of the followings-

```
$code = "123456 - US";
$code = "12-3456 - US";
$code = "WD123 - US";
$code = "A0-12 - US";
$code = "123456 - Poland";
```

How can I find out the first part(like-123456 or A0-12) and the last part(like-US or Poland)?
In PHP using preg_match function.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could use explode to split it into two parts.

```
$split = explode(" - ",$code);
```

That will give you an array with two elements: "123456" and "US"

Comment: Just an additional note, if you want the values in 2 different variables `explode()` and `list()` work well together eg. `list($left, $right) = explode(" - ", $code);`